# Can an Eidolon apply a reach evolution to a weapon attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner

Can an [Eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons) apply a reach evolution to a weapon attack (such as a polearm)?  The wording of the reach evolution does not seem to refer to natural attacks as most other Eidolon attack abilities do.

> Reach (Ex)
>
> One of an eidolon’s attacks is capable of striking at foes at a distance. Pick one attack. The eidolon’s reach with that attack increases by 5 feet.

When combined with a reach weapon, it seems this could easily grant a 15 foot reach.  This seems to be very powerful at low level and I have concerns if this was intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As written, yes, you can combine that with a reach weapon**.

3.X and PF rules are *descriptive*; that is, they generally tend to tell you what you *can* do. The RAW on the statement indicates that you can pick one attack - in the scenario you described, that'd be either 'manufactured weapons' or a specific weapon depending on the DM's interpretation of "one" - and the Eidolon gains another five feet of reach with it. Gaining reach in this fashion is fairly standardized, though this particular ability is not, and the flavor is admittedly a little odd.