# Unchained Summoner and Eidolons Reach Evolution for multiple weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, eidolon

I am building an Eidolon from unchained summoner and I need to clarify some things. My Eidolon will have multiple arms (4+) and I plan on giving it weapons. I would like to take the reach evolution which increases the Eidolon's reach by 5 feet for one attack. Does it apply to a single weapon, or all the weapons? This assumes of course that all the weapons will be the same.

There is a [similar question here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22076/23058) but it deals with a singular weapon, and not multiple so my question is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qjz) related to this:

> ## Summoner: If I choose the reach evolution for my eidolon, how many of its attacks gains increased reach?
>
> The ability description says "pick one attack," not "pick one attack type." So if your eidolon has two claws and you pick "claw" for the reach evolution, only one claw gets increased reach. (The reach evolution is intended to let you emulate having a dragon-eidolon, as a dragon's bite attack has greater reach than its claws.)

If we extrapolate that out, if you have 4 manufactured weapons only one such manufactured weapon would gain the reach, even if they're all the same weapon

**Note:** This FAQ is for the chained summoner, though I feel it's still relevant to unchained as well, considering the *Reach* evolution for both chained and unchained is worded exactly the same. So, absent any specific wording elsewhere for the unchained eidolon, I would say the intention is the same, and this FAQ applies.

Comment: I would like to point out that your reference is for the chained summoner and not unchained summoner but I expect the answer to be the same. Thanks for pointing out the FAQ. I figured that was the answer but I can dare to dream.

Comment: I mean. You can always just go the cheese route and give your eidolon 13 extra pairs of arms by 20th level. Nothing like a full round of 28 attacks drop 2 pairs of arms for a large eidolon and they all get damage bonus and 10ft reach!

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this while looking at the possibilities and felt like it was worth pointing out.

**Giving your eidolon a size boost, will grant it reach for ALL attacks!**

> Large (Ex)
>
> Source: PRG:APG
>
> An eidolon grows in size, becoming Large. The eidolon gains a +8 bonus to Strength, a +4 bonus to Constitution, and a +2 bonus to its natural armor. It takes a –2 penalty to its Dexterity. This size change also gives the creature a –1 size penalty to its AC and on attack rolls, a +1 bonus to its CMB and CMD, a –2 penalty on Fly skill checks, and a –4 penalty on Stealth skill checks. If the eidolon has the biped base form, **it also gains 10-foot reach**. Any reach evolutions the eidolon possesses are added to this total. The eidolon must be Medium to take this evolution. The summoner must be at least 8th level before selecting this evolution.
>
> If 6 additional evolution points are spent, the eidolon instead becomes Huge. The eidolon gains a +16 bonus to Strength, a +8 bonus to Constitution, and a +5 bonus to its natural armor. It takes a –4 penalty to its Dexterity. This size change also give the creature a –2 size penalty to its AC and attack rolls, a +2 bonus to its CMB and CMD, 10-foot reach, a –4 penalty on Fly skill checks, and a –8 penalty on Stealth skill checks. **If the eidolon has the biped base form, its reach increases to 15 feet (10 feet for all other base forms)**. Any reach evolutions the eidolon possesses are added to this total. These bonuses and penalties replace, and do not stack with, those gained from becoming Large. The summoner must be at least 13th level before selecting this option.

While reach alone wont grant it to all your attacks, You could make your eidolon large or huge to give it 10-15 ft reach!

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, but I was aware that the large evolution did this. The nice part is that enlarge person will still work with the evolution granting you a huge Eidolon (or greater if you spend the evolution points for huge).

Comment: While you might have known, others visiting this page looking to get their Eidolon reach may not have. Still good to have all the relevant info in one place ^.^ (and yes giant eidolons are scary.)